# Bootstrap CSS Menu Box Type Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a site in Bootstrap and am unable to achieve making a simple menu.

I want to make something like this:
[image]

So far I have achieved this:
[image]

I tried but cant make my CSS to work properly.

Here is my CSS Code:

```
.navbar-nav li a {
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your HTML syntax.

Comment: remember that if you want to display something like the first image above. you have to use 2 different class. the most common way to achieve this is to add a css class (commonly named as "active") on the item that you want to have the borders.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gward90/h8cnbL5w/1/

To adjust the look of your buttons play with the padding of `.nav>li>a` Thats a BS default css class. The default padding value is set to `padding: 10px 15px`

You also need to remove the height from your .navbar-nav li a class that is whats making your buttons so large you also don't need the line-height.